# Creating a method that functions as both a class and instance method

Tags: ruby, oop

Let's say I had a class and I wanted to be able to call the same method on the class itself *and* an instance of that class:

```
class Foo
  def self.bar
    puts 'hey this worked'
  end
end
```

This lets me do the following:

```
Foo.bar #=> hey this worked
```

But I also want to be able to do:

```
Foo.new.bar #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `bar' for #<Foo:0x007fca00945120>
```

So now I modify my class to have an instance method for `bar`:

```
class Foo
  def bar
    puts 'hey this worked'
  end
end
```

And now I can call bar on both the class and an instance of the class:

```
Foo.bar #=> hey this worked
Foo.new.bar #=> hey this worked
```

Now my class `Foo` is 'wet':

```
class Foo
  def self.bar
    puts 'hey this worked'
  end

  def bar
    puts 'hey this worked'
  end
end
```

Is there a way to avoid this redundancy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have one method call the other. Otherwise, no, there is no way to avoid this "redundancy", because there *is* no redundancy. There are two separate methods that happen to have the same name.

```
class Foo
  def self.bar
    puts 'hey this worked'
  end

  def bar
    Foo.bar
  end
end
```